# Toolset Types display custom term field

Tags: term-meta

In Toolset Types I created a custom term field named "cp" with a color picker.

I'm trying to use the color in a title but I can't make it work. I searched the DB and found the field as "wpcf-cp" so I tried to use it but it didn't help.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_query->the_post();
            ?>
            
            <div class="catalogue_item">
                <h2 style="color:<?php types_render_termmeta( "wpcf-cp", array() ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">lien vers la fiche</a>
                <p>
                    <?php foreach ( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {
                        echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
                    }?>
                </p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
?>
```

If you can tell me what's wrong it would help me greatly.

Thank you for reading